# Turn a flat mesh into sphere (for eyes)

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I'm working with a model that has flat meshes for eyes. I want to turn these flat meshes into spheres so I can better work with the eyes for posing. How do I either make the flat meshes spherical, or how can I make a sphere that can shape around the flat surfaces?

BTW, here are some methods I have already tried:
Shrinkwrap modifier on sphere: This led to a weirdly deformed and too flat sphere.
Shrinkwrap modifier on lattice parent of sphere: Slightly better results but still has bad deforming.

Comment: Can you add screesnhots for better understanding? Why don't you delete the flat surface of your mesh and add a sphere instead of it?

Answer (score 2):

You can **cast** to a sphere using a modifier or an operator with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>:

[image]